# Try Except String vs Int Python

Tags: python, int, type-conversion

I am not sure whether to use try/except or an if condition to detect whether a number is an int or a float.  I know my input is either a float or an int, and I want to raise a value error for all floats, and do something if the number is an int.  An example of where this type of behavior might be seen is a factorial...  However, I don't want a 5.0 to be converted to a 5.  What is the best approach?

```
factorial(5)
> 120
factorial(asdf)
> ValueError
factorial(5.0)
> ValueError
```

I read this question [Parse String to Float or Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int) but I am still confused

Comment: I would suggest that you don't detect type of input at all. If you simply implement your `factorial` not caring about type of input, it will probably (a) work for types which make sense, and (b) raise an execption for other types anyway.

Comment: What `factorial` function are you talking about? Is it one you've written?

Comment: @tdelaney Im pretty sure its just `math.factorial` but a good question all the same

Comment: I don't think it matters.  I am just using a factorial as an example where I want to draw the distinction between floats and ints.  The actual use is for analyzing English Soccer data that I scraped without an API so it is a bit messy.  I could do it another way, but since I had the thought and didn't know the solution I figured I would ask.  The question is more theoretical...

Comment: @qwertylpc Your question is confusing. If you are talking about type checking and raising exceptions, how about a small example that does that? Your `factorial` example doesn't seem to have much to do with anything.

Comment: @JoranBeasley `math.factorial` doesn't raise a ValueError with `5.0`. I was hoping to prod OP into an example that has something to do with his problem.

Comment: The only way you can use try/except is if you attempt some operation that requires a float and raises an exception on fail. `isinstance` makes more sense. You link to a question about strings... could this thing you want to check be a string that you plan to convert to an int? If so `'.' in asdf` would be a good check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this solution counts on the fact that `int("1.235")` will raise a value error as for a string to convert it **must** be a **literal int**.  This requires `my_value` to be a string! as `int(1.235)` will simply truncate the float to an int

```
my_value = raw_input("Enter Value")

try:
  my_value = int(my_value)
except ValueError:
  try:
     float(my_value)
     print "Its a float not an int!"
     raise ValueError("Expected Int, got Float!")
  except ValueError:
     print "Its a string not a float or int"
     raise TypeError("Expected Int, got String!")
else:
  print "OK its an int"
```

Comment: You should remove the `raise` otherwise it still raises an error

Comment: I assumed he would want to catch it else where if that is not the case then yes the raise should be removed

Comment: Note that, like in your example, it must be ensured that `my_value` is originally a string. Otherwise this would still pass floats.

Comment: raw_input is guaranteed to return a string ... but yes duly noted

Comment: @JoranBeasley if OP just wants a valueError raised if not an int then you don't need the second try except statement

Comment: he wants to diferentiate @SirParselot between the input type it sounds like  (IE he wants to know if it was a string, or if it was a float , not just that it was invalid)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Eh it's whatever. It works and makes sense +1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to typesafely check if the variable is an int, you can use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
def factorial(var):
    if not isinstance(var, int):
        raise ValueError('var must be an int')
    # do stuff
```

This would also raise a `ValueError` for any string obviously (so `"5"` wouldn't work, if that's what you want).

Comment: I think this is a resonable solution since it advises `isinstance` (which is so much better than `type(x)` ) ... so +1 ... but I dont think this will quite solve the problem the OP has (all the same +1 for `isinstance`)